# Can I extend a Typescript tuple type?

Tags: typescript, tuples

Say I have a Typescript tuple:

```
type Sandwich = [name: string, toppings: object]
```

Now I want to extend it:

```
type HotDog = [name: string, toppings: object, length: number]
```

Can `HotDog` extend `Sandwich` without duplication?

Answer (score 2):

Just spread one into the other:

```
type Sandwich = [name: string, toppings: object]
type HotDog = [...sandwich: Sandwich, length: number]
//   ^ type is [name: string, toppings: object, length: number]
```

[See Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAyghgOwCYHcCWBjAFlAvFAbQTgFsIAuKAZ2ACc0EBzAGimAHswwHGrL2ARgCsIGYAF0AsAChQkKAAl2wACLtGeQgDodVRKkxZK8ZOmysANhCbAjUBAFcSAiLSnSA9B6g+AegH4gA)